# How do you print out multiple words from a file?

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, stringbuilder

I am having trouble printing out a list of words from a file.

******No error, just nothing prints out******

Here is the female_names.txt file:

Mary
Michelle
Patricia
Linda
Barbara
Elizabeth
Jennifer
Maria
Susan
Margaret
Dorothy
Lisa
Nancy
Karen
Betty
Helen
Sandra
Donna
Carol
Ruth
Sharon
Michelle
Laura
Sarah
Kimberly
Deborah
Jessica
Shirley
Cynthia
Angela
Melissa
Brenda
Amy
Anna
Rebecca
Virginia
Kathleen
Pamela
Martha
Debra

OPEN FILE : opens a file and has a main

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OpenFile 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        BufferedReader femaleFile = null;
        BufferedReader maleFile = null;
        try
        {
            femaleFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/Luna/Desktop/female_names.txt"));
            maleFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/Luna/Desktop/males_names.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         String femaleLine = null;
         String maleLine = null;

         try 
         {
                System.out.println("FEMALE LIST" +"  ===  "+"MALE LIST");
            while((femaleLine = femaleFile.readLine())!= null)
            {
              maleLine = maleFile.readLine();
                if(maleLine != null)
                {

                    System.out.println(femaleLine+"  ===  "+maleLine);
                }
             }
         } catch (IOException e) 
         {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         System.out.println("\n");


                    //------------User Input ------------//
         //-------picking a single random male or female word-------//
         PickRandomWord p = new PickRandomWord();
         p.pickFemaleWord();
         System.out.println(" ");
         p.pickMaleWord();


//THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK

         PickMultipleWords e = new PickMultipleWords();
         e.pickFemaleWords(2);

    }



}
```

Here is my other class that should print out a list of random words from the female names text file

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class PickMultipleWords
{

    public String pickFemaleWords(int length) 
    {

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/Luna/Desktop/female_names.txt"));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
            while(line != null) 
            {
                String[] wordsLine = line.split(" ");
                for(String word : wordsLine)
                {
                    words.add(word);
                }
                line = reader.readLine();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // Handle this
        }

        Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        StringBuilder wordHere = new StringBuilder(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
        {
            wordHere.append((char)('a' + rand.nextInt(26)));
        }
        return wordHere.toString();




    }


}
```

Comment: please mention what error are you facing

Comment: No error, just nothing prints out

Answer (score 0):

You are not printing the result after `pickFemaleWords` method is called:

```
PickMultipleWords e = new PickMultipleWords();
String result = e.pickFemaleWords(2);
System.out.println("*** Random names ***");
System.out.println(result);
```